# `main` function not found in crate `rust_out`: consider adding a `main` function at the crate level on vim/ale

Tags: vim, rust

I have some Rust code that just has another modu

```
// main.rs
mod foo;
fn main() {
    foo::hello();
}

// foo.rs
pub fn hello() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

But vim ale https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale keeps claiming:

```
`main` function not found in crate `rust_out`: consider adding a `main` function at the crate level
```

Here is the configuration

```
...
Plug 'rust-lang/rust.vim'
...
let g:ale_linters = {
      \   'rust': ['rls', 'rustc', 'cargo'],
      \ }
...
```

`cargo build` runs fine, it's something on ale that is going wrong!?

Comment: For anyone interested I'm using syntastic for rust instead of ale,